# Erro angular-devkit/build-angular

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli

tenho no package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project src/tsconfig.json --type-check && tslint \"e2e/**/*.ts\" --project e2e/tsconfig.json --type-check",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "8.1.0",
    "admin-lte": "2.4.12",
    "ajv": "6.10.1",
    "core-js": "3.1.4",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.5.2",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "0.9.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.9",
    "@angular/cli": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.1.0",
    "@types/express": "4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.3.13",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.6",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "8.3.2",
    "@types/node": "12.6.1",
    "codelyzer": "5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "json-server": "0.12.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "karma": "^4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.2",
    "protractor": "^6.0.0",
    "ts-node": "8.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.18.0",
    "typescript": "3.5.3",
    "webdriver-manager": "12.1.5"
}
```

porem quando rodo ng serve apresenta o erro:

```
Error: Could not find the implementation for builder @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server
    at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.resolveBuilder (/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js:49:19)
    at ServeCommand.initialize (/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:135:55)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: Já tentou excluir a pasta `node_modules` e instalar as dependências novamente com `npm install`? Pode ser algum arquivo/pacote que esteja faltando

Comment: sim já fiz isso, não só o node_modules e package-lock.json que eu exclui.